# Access specific array node bu name

Tags: jquery, arrays

I would like to access the 'Celebrity' node from the following array node, the node itself is within the first array tier so accesed via:

```
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {


      var celItem = data[0];
      console.log($(celItem));

    });
```

[image]

ABove is the Chrom console log..  I'm having a mind melt - can anyone give me a quick push in the right direction?

Comment: provide html too

Comment: What is fitsitem? What does it have to do with the loop you have?

Comment: Is the screenshot the output of that `console.log` you have in the code? If yes, how does that relate to `data`?

Comment: @trincot maybe he has a `var data = $(fitsitem)` somewhere?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy, Yes maybe, or maybe not: it would be nice to know.

Comment: When you say "node", do you mean object? The console output does not show anything that looks like a DOM node...

Comment: sorry - screenshot above is the chrome console log and celitem is simply the first element of the data array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `data` is an array with one object element, you don't need a loop. Just access the property you need:

```
data[0].Celebrities
```

As that is an array itself, you can iterate over it:

```
data[0].Celebrities.forEach(function(celebrity) { 
    console.log(celebrity);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, apologies for the confusing question!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check if the current loop key is `Celebrities` then you initialize the variable using it's value.

```js
var str = '{"VenueName": "SuperTheatre", "Celebrities": [1,2,3], "Schedules": [4,5,6]}';
var data = JSON.parse(str);
$.each(data, function(key, val) {

  if (key == "Celebrities") {
    var celItem = val;
    console.log(celItem);
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
```